# Add another profile link not working

Tags: civievent, wordpress, 4.7

None of the "add another profile" links on the Event/Online Registration tab are working. The page just refreshes. This is the first time I have tried to edit an Event with this version of civicrm -- I recall this this worked previously. As shown below, my form lacks quite a few buttons.

Example from demo site:
[image: Image of form on demo site]

Example of my form:
[image: Image of my form]

Comment: Not working in 4.7.1 either.

Comment: Paul, we have this working in 4.6.x and 4.7.1.   I've seen plugins block the profile block from loading.  Can you disable plugins to determine where the conflict is?  I typically turn them all off and then enable one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin in the comments section. It was a plugin called Kadence Slider causing the problem. This plugin and the Kadence themes are not compatible with CiviCRM.